# Why middle elements of transition series show more number of oxidation states

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state, periodic-trends

Why do the elements in the middle of the transition series show more number of common oxidation states than others?

[image]

Comment: Because they have more valence electrons to play with. Earlier elements have too few outside the core, and later ones tend to have their $d$ electrons sinking into said core. I will add that gold is known up to +5.

Comment: You say they show more number of oxidation states, and I say you got lame data. That's only most common ox. states.

Comment: Yep I wanted to mean common oxidation states.

Comment: Unfortunately what's common is opinion based ;>

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67510/why-do-heavier-transition-metals-show-higher-oxidation-states

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61353/why-do-osmium-and-iridium-have-the-most-oxidation-states-of-all-the-elements